# Use of No with Hence in a Sentence

Tags: grammar

1. No technical support, hence fix, will be available for the system bug.
2. No technical support, hence no fix, will be available for the system bug.
3. No technical support, hence no fix will be available for the system bug.

I would like to know which of the 3 sentences above is correct.  I know sentence 3 is most likely the correct one.  I used sentence 1 in my report writeup but was asked to amend to use the sentence 2 version.  Can anyone explain?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

**hence means therefore**. These terms can be placed at the beginning of a sentence  or in the middle of a compound or complex sentence.

[there is] **No technical support, hence, no fix will be available for the system bug.**

The comma, in this bullet-style sentence, should come after hence.

**In full**, a sentence like that would look like this: There is no technical support. Hence, no fix will be available for the system bug. However, the word hence can be placed in the middle and followed by a comma.

Regardless of where the word hence is placed (at the beginning or in the middle of a sentence, it would normally be followed by a comma and if what follows it is one idea, that idea should be stated in full and not truncated as in 2).

- "no fix, will be available" should be: "no fix will be available"